# How to copy text from a column to another worksheet without duplicates?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets. Worksheet 1: "Data", Worksheet 2: "Evaluation".

In the worksheet "Data" thousands of names of employees are in column "E" starting with "E10". The names of these employees are repeated several times in this column. The name "Dave" can also occur 100 times.

I need a VBA function / instruction which writes the name of an employee on the worksheet "Evaluation" in one row, the second employee in the next row, etc.

Each employee should only be listed once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
Sub Olaf()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, n As Long

    n = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r1 = Sheets("Data").Range("E10:E" & n)
    Set r2 = Sheets("Evaluation").Range("A1")

    r1.Copy r2

    Sheets("Evaluation").Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

Change `r2` to change the destination cell.